# Scala trait runtime class from type parameter

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I have a scala trait [this trait does not compile]

```
trait MyTrait[T <: Enum] {
  def myMethod(name: String): T = {
    MyJavaClass.staticMethod(name, classOf[T])
  }
}
```

And a Java class

```
public class MyJavaClass {
    public static <T extends Enum> T staticMethod(String name, Class<T> c) {
        return (T) T.valueOf(c, name);
    }
}
```

How can I make the trait valid scala? What I'm currently doing is adding a `Class[T]` field like this

```
trait MyTrait[T <: Enum] {
  val t: Class[T]

  def myMethod(name: String): T = {
    MyJavaClass.staticMethod(name, t)
  }
}
```

but I don't like having to add a `t` field to all classes that want to use this trait.

Comment: what compilation error do you get?

Comment: `classOf[T]` is not a valid expression

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice and common way of working around type erasure in Scala is to use `ClassTag`s.
They're usually passed as implicit parameters. Unfortunately, traits can't take constructor parameters, so the best that we can have is:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait MyTrait[T <: Enum] {
  val ttag: ClassTag[T]

  def myMethod(name: String): T = {
    MyJavaClass.staticMethod(name, ttag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
  }
}
```

Then, every class extending `MyTrait` must be defined like this:

```
class MyClass[T <: Enum](/*your params, if any*/)(implicit val ttag: ClassTag[T]) extends MyTrait[T] {
  /*your class body*/
}
```

Then, if you have some concrete enum `MyEnum`, you can create instances of your class seamlessly:

```
new MyClass[MyEnum](/*your params, if any*/)
```

Comment: This looks similar to using a `Manifest`.

Comment: @three-cups Yes, `ClassTag`s and `TypeTag`s are Scala 2.10's replacement for `Manifest` (although in production `TypeTag`s should be rather avoided since they are not yet production quality).

Comment: thanks good to know! It's tough keeping up with Scala sometimes :)

Comment: I'm no Scala expert so I don't know if there's some subtle reason not to do it this way, but in an analogous situation of my own I was able to  reduce some of the boilerplate.  I defined the implicit val within the trait itself, and didn't need to also declare it in the subclass: `implicit val ttag: ClassTag[T] = classTag[T]` (with an import for `scala.reflect.classTag`).  Is there any reason not to do it this way?

Comment: @M.Justin you've just fallen into a classic implicit trap. Your `implicit val` refers to itself (recursively) and it's going to be `null`

Comment: @ghik Why is that?  I'm not having much luck finding anywhere that discusses this (which probably just means that I'm not searching for the right terms).

Comment: @M.Justin the way you've defined `ttag`, its implementation just looks for implicit `ClassTag[T]` and... finds the `ttag` itself as matching implicit, therefore creating a cycle. If it was a `def` instead of `val`, you would get a stack overflow or infinite loop.

Comment: @ghik So assigning it the value of `classTag[T]` isn't actually doing anything?

Comment: @M.Justin it's like writing `implicit ttag: ClassTag[T] = ttag`